# android webview back button setOnClickListener

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-webview

I set a button on my main layout that should execute goBack method of webview that is set on another layout. Application crashes when setOnClickListener for backButton. What I am doing wrong? Thank you.

webView class,

```
 public class webPush extends Activity {

        WebView webview; 
        Button backButton;

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.webview); 

            webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);

            backButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

            backButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {
                  @Override 
                  public void onClick(View arg0) 
                  {
                      webview.goBack();
                  }
            });

            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);       

            webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

            webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

        }
```

from main layout,

```
<Button
                 android:id="@+id/button1"
                 style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                 android:layout_width="78dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="0.02"
                 android:text="Back" />
```

Comment: what's the crash report?, also, you need to make sure that there IS a page to go back to

Comment: says not too much... unable to start activity

Comment: please post all of the report, maybe we'de be able to see something you missed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in which layout u have placed button? is it in main.xml or webview layout?
if the button is in main.xml then setContentView(R.layout.main);

Comment: u are getting nullpointer exception for button. my question is do u have that button with button id as button1 in webview layout?

Comment: ?? button is placed on main layout, webview is placed on webview layout. Button should receive an action and make webview go back.

Comment: the prob as far i know is u r setting webview layout and trying get button id which is not present in that webview layout that why the button is null and throws null pointer exception.. can u place the webview.xml

Comment: for any other reasons button must be placed on main layout :( so probably this is the issue... Is there any way to set it from main one?

Comment: when i commented setOnClickListener() and tried your code i am getting the webview layout.. i just want to know where you want to navigate from that page and on click of which button?

Comment: mm ok, I changed some code in order to set button on same layout. Working! I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3):

I think you have nullpointer exception....because...`webview is null`

put this line after setcontentview...

```
  webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
```

Comment: I do not know how to attach complete log file. If this line is not enough please advise, E/AndroidRuntime(374): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nb.TabBar/com.nb.TabBar.webPush}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: You must be seeing a red color stuff in your  logcat rite?? just click on the first line then press shift and click on the last line where the RED texts ends. Press Ctrl+C and Ctrl+v on your fav notepad. Datz it you'll have locat. Without logcat it'd be very difficult to diagnose such problems. Good luck.

Comment: I changed some code in order to get button on same webview layout. I aprpreciate your help. Thank you. +1

Answer (score 0):

try adding this:

```
if (ourBrowser.canGoBack()) {
            ourBrowser.goBack();
}
```

Comment: crashes when setOnClickListener for button object. Not a solution